# create dummy SearchResponse instance for ElasticSearch test case using scala

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, scalatest

Is there a way, I can create a variable of SearchResponse type with 0 hits?

I am struggling to create one for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

What I do for unit test is to use a HTTP mock server, and map some elasticsearch entrypoints (such as _search, "PUT /index/doc" etc...) to mocked responses.

I use `org.mockserver` (http://www.mock-server.com/), I wrote a small post about it: https://medium.com/@thomasdecaux/mock-elasticsearch-with-mock-server-5811cf141035

Basically, you mock elasticsearch routes like this:

```
this.client.when(
                HttpRequest.request()
                        .withPath(".*/_search")
        ).respond(toHttpResponse(new JSONObject(map("took", 10, "hits" , map("total", 0)))));
```

Comment: I use it to test elasticsearch and elasticsearch4hadoop plugin, with Spark.